# KonvaJS: event.preventDefault is not a function

Tags: javascript, dom-events, kineticjs, konvajs

Nowadays I am playing with [KonvaJS](http://konvajs.github.io/docs/). I have set a `click` event listener on a `shape`. When I click on `shape`, the listener is invoked. In my listener I am invoking `event.preventDefault()` method to stop triggering of other events. But when I do so it says that:

> Uncaught TypeError: event.preventDefault is not a function

I don't know what I am missing. Here is my [code](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ds0ypkF9cgqZptLxN2ks?p=preview) :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/konvajs/konva/0.9.5/konva.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Konva Scale Animation Demo</title>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #F0F0F0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container"></div>
  <script>
    var width = window.innerWidth;
    var height = window.innerHeight;

    var stage = new Konva.Stage({
      container: 'container',
      width: width,
      height: height
    });

    var layer = new Konva.Layer();

    stage.add(layer);

    var gArrow2 = new Image();
     var circle2 = new Konva.Image({

        x: 60, //on canvas
        y: 60,
        image: gArrow2,
        name: 'abc',
        id: 'xyz',
        draggable:true
      });
      circle2.on('click',function(event){
        event.preventDefault()
        console.log(e.type);
      });
      circle2.on('mouseup',function(event){
         event.preventDefault()
        console.log(e.type);
      });
    gArrow2.onload = function() {
     
      layer.add(circle2);
      layer.draw();
    }
    gArrow2.src = 'http://konvajs.github.io/assets/snake.png';

    var period = 1500;
    var amplitude = 10;
    var centerX = stage.getWidth() / 2;
    var centerY = stage.getHeight() / 2;

    var anim = new Konva.Animation(function(frame) {
      circle2.setY(amplitude * Math.sin(frame.time * 2 * Math.PI / period) + centerY);
    }, layer);

    anim.start();
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: See Konva docs for [cancelBubble](https://konvajs.org/docs/events/Cancel_Propagation.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that KonvaJS's `on` handler does not give you directly the browser events but an object that looks like: [image].

The browser's original event is stored in the `evt` property.

In your code, try to replace `event.preventDefault()` by `event.evt.preventDefault()`: http://plnkr.co/edit/tCESd42r67TzeuLiISxU.

Comment: You nailed it brother. thanks. Can I stop triggering `mouseup` event when user clicks on shape?

Comment: If you want to remove the default operations on click, preventing on the click event is sufficient. No need to call `preventDefault` on `mouseup` too.

Answer (score 1):

If you want other events not to be triggered then `KonvaJS` has a property called `cancelBubble` for `event` which you can set to `true`. By using this need not to look for `event.preventDefault()` function. Here's the  [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/H9v9ySOhGNdiekOwvGq9?p=preview) to demonstrate.

```
triangle.on('mouseup', function(e) {
      e.cancelBubble = true;
      console.log('Triangle mouse up');
    });
```